# worklight protecting mobile application using predefined security 'mobilesecuritytest'

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I am building a custom authenticator and login module, and i have went through the tutorials and information.

I am able to achieve the security using security test defined on adapter but i want to leverage on the worklight predefined security test 'mobilesecuritytest' with my customized realm which is as advised on the documentation.

I couldn't find much information on the usage except only configuration via the application-descriptor.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed information about security tests in the following blog post: [Understanding predefined Worklight authentication realms and security tests](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en).

There is no much else to it. You define the structure of the security tes in authenticationConfig.xml and apply it on the environment in application-descriptor.xml.

Take note of figure #3, showing an example of the pre-defined mobileSecurityTest used with a custom authentication realm.

[image]

Quote:

> As you can see, the structure of the security tests has remained
>   unchanged, however it is no longer using the default
>   wl_anonymousUserRealm to identify users but a MyUserAuthRealm created
>   by developer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying i have ran through this blog previously. My implementation is a hybrid application using my own login page and with 'mobileSecurityTest' configured overridden with my own realm. Btw, what is 'isInternalUserID'? I did further exploration since the post and i realise that i have to invoke WL.Client.Login before showing the login page and then submission of the credentials. Strangely, tracing through it actually authenticates successfully but an abort action after against my login module will utimately fail the login; this seems to be invoked by the wl framework.

Comment: A little bit more, here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/c_security_config.html